# Laravel Send Mail with Yahoo SMTP: Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, smtp, yahoo-mail

I wanna to send mail with Yahoo SMTP service but return error in Laravel 5.5:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable "
```

Before that I tested send mail with Gmail SMTP service, every things is ok, but about Yahoo I have problem. My `.env` configuration is:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@yahoo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I send mail with this code:

```
public function sendMail(){
        $data = []; // Empty array
        Mail::send('welcome', $data, function($message)
        {
            $message->to('john.doe@outlook.com', 'John Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
        });
        return 'ok';
    }
```

Even I active SMTP from Yahoo mail configuration:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS** is required and the value is just equal to MAIL_USERNAME.

Your **.env** should be like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@yahoo.com
MAIL_USERNAME=example@yahoo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have had the same error in a few different systems. Setting the mail "from" address to XXXX@yahoo.com(like in your config) solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

If your `.env` file is not wrong and you are sure of that, you need clear config cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```